# How to change Apache Environment PATH variable

Tags: php, apache

In the phpinfo, the path shows to `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16` and several other paths are shown. These are not correct anymore. How can I change them manually? I didn't find anything in the config files. (On Windows)

Comment: It would be more useful if you specified the Section and Label of the fields in the phpinfo report that you believe you want to change. Then you would get help and not **guesses**

Comment: And **who on earth is upvoting** questions that are definitely not worth an upvote **?????** Please stop it.

Comment: Configuration/Apache Environment/PATH... Though it was clear in the heading.

Comment: Good lord, That is your Windows PATH!!! Change that and then restart apache, it will pick up your new PATH. Maybe your whole windows system will run better then as well as it will be able to find things properly.

Comment: I still not know HOW to change it...

Comment: Then maybe you should consider a career in Sales. [See this](http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/) **or do a google search on** _windows change path environment variable_